# How can I show the latest/last product products that has been added DB from my controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making an ecommerce store and I want to show the latest record that has been added from the database using my product controller. Can anyone who's an expert at laravel kindly assist? I have not idea on how to do that.

Here's the code from my controller, that's displaying products on the landing page

```
public function index()
  {
  return view('/welcome')->with([
  'products' => $this->getProducts(4),
]);
}

public function getProducts(int $limit) {
return Product::orderByDesc('created_at')->skip(0)->take($limit)->get();
}
```

After implementing this update that was recommended that was recommended and closing the 'created_at' string, I'm getting an error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'. Is there anyway I can get rid of this error?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest Check the documentation  "Latest" can mean different things depending on your database, latest from `created_at`, or latest from `updated_at`, or most recent (highest) ID, etc etc, but you can use that method, or `orderBy('whatever', 'DESC')`, etc etc.

Comment: I'd like to know how to implement 'created_at'. I don't know whether to create a new function or use the ones I already have.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamp, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps. Once again, please read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your product table has some datetime column then you'll have to order by that column as you want to show your latest results.
So you can modify your query like below

```
Product::orderByDesc('created_at)->offset(0)->limit($limit)->get();
```

Or you can make use of the alternative skip and take method

```
Product::orderByDesc('created_at)->skip(0)->take($limit)->get();
```

If you don't have a datetime column (`created_at` in this case) and your `Product` model has auto incrementing `id` column then you can just do

```
Product::orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(0)->take($limit)->get();
```

For more info please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

Comment: Sidenote, `skip(0)` and/or `offset(0)` are optional here; they're implied  But otherwise, great answer!

Comment: So should it be like 'public function getProducts(int $limit) {
    Product::orderByDesc('created_at')->offset(0)->limit($limit)->get();
 }'? Because when I added that line, it gave me an error. Pardon, I'm just fairly new at using laravel

Comment: @Ben Instead of saying "I got an error from doing X", why don't you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69904881/edit) and include your new code, and any new errors that come from it. Saying "it gave me an error" alone is not useful.

Comment: @Mosharaf. It worked. Thank you so much.